# stringForKey Crashes App

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to store a string in NSUserDefaults, however when I go to retrieve it, my app crashes.

I assume this only happens the first time, since a value has never been set for that key in NSUserDefaults, however I have tried adding some code in `viewDidLoad()` to set it the first time and this doesn't seem to help.

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    itemSelected = "Moss"
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(itemSelected, forKey: "colourChosen")
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    itemSelected = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("colourChosen")!
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    itemSelected = colours[row]
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(itemSelected, forKey: "colourChosen")
}
```

The app crashes in `viewWillAppear()`

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling `synchronize()` after setting the object:

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setObject(itemSelected, forKey: "colourChosen")
userDefaults.synchronize()
             ^^^^
```

Without that, no change is immediately saved. That might be the cause.

`synchronize` must be invoked every time you make changes to the user defaults, and you want to immediately persist the changes (the system automatically calls it at specific time intervals).

However, in your `viewWillAppear` implementation I notice that you are using forced unwrapping, which you should always avoid unless you are 100% sure the optional actually contains a non nil value. I'd protect that unwrapping with an optional binding:

```
if let colour = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("colourChosen") {
    itemSelected = color
}
```

---

**Update**

I notice that `itemSelected` is a temporary container for what you store in the user defaults. You might consider moving the user defaults code in a computed property, to prevent code duplication every time that property is read or modified - something like:

```
private var _itemSelected : String?

var itemSelected : String? {
    get {
        if _itemSelected == nil {
            _itemSelected = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("colourChosen")
        }
        return _itemSelected
    }
    set {
        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        userDefaults.setObject(newValue, forKey: "colourChosen")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }
}
```

where the `_itemSelected` is just a cached value - or similar implementation but without the cached value:

```
var itemSelected : String? {
    get {
        return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("colourChosen")
    }
    set {
        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        userDefaults.setObject(newValue, forKey: "colourChosen")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Note that in both cases the property type is an optional string

Comment: That's not the issue unfortunately. Are you certain you have to use `synchronise()`? I've use NSUserDefaults many times and never had to use it before.

Comment: It's automatically invoked at periodic intervals, but if you want the changes to be immediately available it's better to use it. That might be your case, although it doesn't solve the issue. Can you post in your question what exception you have?

Comment: I didn't notice the `!` at the end of the line in `viewWillAppear`. That makes a forced unwrapping, and most likely is the reason of the exception if the key doesn't exist. I suggest to wrap that in an optional binding

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was about to reply to say that none of the solutions were working, but I was experiencing an unrelated problem.